# Java set with reduced memory footprint

Tags: java, set, compression

The problem is following: 
We are developing Java client-server product, that require DDoS protection by filtering.
Each request contains client id. 
And if the server receives too much requests from client in a short period of time, client's id will be added to blacklist. 
Server filters requests and if it's id in the black list, request is ignored.

Memory consumption is a problem. It's required to minimize memory consumed by black list.

Using HashSet or TreeSet is not appropriate.

Is there a Java library that implements such a kind of set, where memory footprint is smaller than num_elements * size_of_element? Is it possible?

Or if it's impossible, what is a Java set implementation with minimal memory footprint?

Comment: No, it is not possible to store less data than there is data (!).A  `Set` has a large-ish memory overhead due its performance characteristics - it guarantees uniqueness and has a fast search. A `HashSet` is likely the right choice for your situation. The alternative would be a noSQL store - that would be _significantly_ slower though; whether that matters to you; only you can decide.

Comment: You realize that a DDoS is a *distributed* DoS attack meaning that the attack will most likely *not* be from a single client ID.

Comment: This is not Java's forte to do that; use a dedicated program _in front_ of your main application to take care of this stuff.

Comment: Yes, because it's a distributed attack this problem exists. Dedicated component is a great choice, but I don't know any of such components.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a Java library that implements such a kind of set, where memory footprint is smaller than num_elements * size_of_element?

I'm not aware of such a library.

> Is it possible?

In theory yes.  You could use some form or compression to represent a set of client IP addresses in less space than N * sizeof(IP address).

However ...

The other things that you need (I imagine) are *fast* lookup of IP addresses and *fast* update of the data.  That makes this a difficult problem, especially if you are trying to code this in Java which is not a great language for implementing minimal memory data structures.

---

Actually, there is another way to control memory usage.  Use a LinkedHashMap created with `accessOrder` set to `true`.  That causes the map entried to be ordered in LRU order.  Then each time you add an entry to the map, check that it isn't too big.  If necessary, remove the first entry ... the least recently used one.

Comment: I'm thinking about compression. I have an idea about it: there are message digest algorithms. Algorithm takes input byte sequence and returns fixed length sequence that unique for the input. Can be algorithm that takes many elements as an input (I), returns some result (R) smaller than sum input elements size. Algorithm has a second operation: with given R (result from the first operation) and an element, it can answer that element was in the input.